# using 2 alias together in cshell terminal

Tags: alias, tcsh, csh

lets say I have 2 aliases, each having multiple arguments.
It looks somewhat like below example

```
alias s1 "command1 -a -b -c"
alias s2 "command2 -d -e -f"
```

now if I run :s1 s2 in terminal, it cant recognize s2.
I found that in bash we can add a space after s2 and it works.
Neither that is working in csh, nor it supports function().

Is there any way ?

PS: I actually have various flavors of s1 which I need to combine with flavors of s2.

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you're trying to do. Can you provide more practical example? how should those two commands run together, what is the expected result? Both `s1` and `s2` are  expanded only in command context. They are not variables. If you run `s1 s2`, in your example, the result would be: `command1 -a -b -c s2`, because `s1` is expanded (since it's the first word in the line) but `s2` is not treated as a command or an alias, it's treated as an argument to `s1`. So I don't understand what exactly you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: @aviro hi, s2 does get expanded in bash , if we keep an extra space at the end of the alias statement in RHS. On the practical example side, s1 is actually lsf job launch prefix and s2 is the actual command I am trying to launch in lsf.